# модуль re, особенности работы

Tags: python, re

Всем привет. Есть задача: найти первое слово в строке. В строке могут встречатся точки и запятые
Строка может начинаться с буквы или, к примеру, с пробела или точки. В слове может быть апостроф и он является частью слова. Весь текст может быть представлен только одним словом и все. Первое слово можеть быть представлено 1 буквой.

Используя библиотеку re успешно решил задачу(первый опыт работы с ней)

```
text = "_first'word second word"
result = re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]*'*[a-zA-Z]",text)
result.group()
```

, но появился вопрос: почему если в наведёном коде заменить первую

```
*
```

на

```
+
```

То слова которые представлены 1 буквой, не будут найдены.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` означает, что предыдущая "сущность" (в данном случае последовательность `[a-zA-Z]`) может повторяться 0 и более раз. А `+` означает, что 1 и более раз.
Соответственно, если вы напишите `+`, то выражение будет интерпретироваться как:

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - любая буква (**один** и более раз)
- `'*` - апостроф (**ноль** и более раз)
- `[a-zA-Z]` - любая буква (**одна** штука)

Итого, минимальная последовательность, которая будет соответствовать этому выражению:
1 + 0 + 1 = 2 символа.

Вообще, ваше выражение будет соответствовать словам, к примеру, начинающимся с апострофа, не будет находить слова с апострофом на конце. Если разбирать английские слова, то апостроф на конце вполне может быть (типа *Jones’ car*).
Как по мне логичнее разбирать как читаешь, т.е. сначала обязательное слово из букв, а потом не обязательные апостроф и буквы: `[a-zA-Z]+'?[a-zA-Z]*`. Хотя, буквально в считанных случаях слова и с апострофа могут начинаться (*'cause -> because*), тогда и спереди надо добавить `'?` чтобы сматчилось.